# YouTube Analytics not returning channel metrics

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

API call:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==UCs4uXj0TcstDHqhHDUWlINg&start-date=2016-10-02&end-date=2016-10-02&metrics=views%2ccomments%2clikes%2cdislikes%2cshares%2cestimatedMinutesWatched%2caverageViewDuration%2caverageViewPercentage%2cannotationClickThroughRate%2cannotationCloseRate%2csubscribersGained%2csubscribersLost

token:

ya29

.OAJc4bDrDoA6XVEmCI9KZK6rfIz68aXjibhZFQowWZxHJx7tt0qyvpxUryxtPZtN8IrN

Comment: What error are you getting?  If you're not getting an error what response are you getting?  Are you using a client library?  Are you setting the token as a "Authorization" header with a value of "Bearer " and then your token value?

Comment: I am not getting an error.  The call simply returns no data.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the parameters I used in reports.query [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/reports/query#try-it):

[image]

The correct format in the ids textfield is '`channel=={YOUR_CHANNEL_ID}`'

The response will correspond to the order you enumerated your metrics. For example, the response to the parameters above was:

```
 "rows": [
  [
   201,   
   0,
   9
  ]
 ]
```

meaning:

```
201 - views
0 - likes
9 - comments
```

because my metrics textfield was in this order -> views,likes,comments.

Comment: I am not getting any data when I make the call.  It is simply returning an empty dataset.